# Process.Start .WaitForExit long pause on one single platform only?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a small application built in VB.NET (VS2017). Target .NET framework is set to the default of 4.6.1 for this. On the primary platform of Windows 10, everything works as expected. On the secondary platform of Windows 7 Pro, I am seeing a very very long pause after exiting a process to be able to do other things in the app.

I am calling up an Internet Explorer window and passing a URL using:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", recurl).WaitForExit()
```

Any ideas why it seems to work just fine under Win10, but has a really long pause in Win7?

Comment: Does IE happen to take a long time to close on one computer or have you tried it on several? Maybe IE is set to delete history etc. when it is closed and that is taking some time.

Comment: Interesting observation. I just checked and while the actual window closes just as fast as any other platform, the underlying iexplore.exe process does take a bit more time to close (around 17 seconds). I checked and it's not set to delete the history or clear anything on exit. Is there a better method than .WaitForExit that I can use? The application in question is basically a custom shell for a kiosk and I use .WaitForExit to keep the user in IE until they're done, at which point they can click another button to open a custom full-screen app or shutdown, for example.

Comment: [After closing IE windows iexplore.exe processes are still running non-stop in Task Manager](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/after-closing-ie-windows-iexploreexe-processes-are/a3b1536d-1732-4f63-92d3-8fa927946d80?page=4&auth=1) contains a suggestion that it could be add-ons in IE causing the slow exit. Can you start IE with the [-extoff flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it and reply.

Comment: if that all fails..you could always poll and check when the main window closes...rather than waiting on the process as a whole

Comment: I use .WaitForExit basically to keep IE in the foreground and my app in the background. Since it's running as a shell, without .WaitForExit, you can click my app and the IE window disappears. If I could find a better way to keep IE in the foreground or my app in the background regardless, that would be even more ideal than using .WaitForExit.

Comment: Can confirm -extoff makes no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @user9241571 Ctznkane525 has already mentioned my next suggestion. Although, as it's for a kiosk, would it be possible for you to specify Windows 10 so that the Windows 7 problem doesn't happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, the client is a government entity and these will still be in use for awhile. I'm going to discuss with the lead developer what his thoughts are, but I'm still open to any and all suggestions going forward. Thank you for the suggestions thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggested extension method.  The idea behind it is that you check you see if the window is open, then checks to see if it closed.  The MainWindowHandle is the handle associated with the pointer for the window.

```
Public Module ProcessExtensionMethods

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub WaitForWindowHandleToClose(ByVal p As System.Diagnostics.Process, ByVal pollingInterval As Integer,
                                          ByVal waitForOpenTimeout As Integer, ByVal waitForCloseTimeout As Integer)

        ' Wait for Main Window Handle to Exist
        Dim totalSleep As Integer
        While Not p.HasExited AndAlso p.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval)
            totalSleep += pollingInterval
            p.Refresh()
            If totalSleep >= waitForOpenTimeout And Not waitForOpenTimeout = 0 Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("Waiting too long for process to start")
            End If
        End While

        ' Wait for Main Window Handle to Close
        totalSleep = 0
        While Not p.HasExited AndAlso p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt64 > 0
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval)
            totalSleep += pollingInterval
            p.Refresh()
            If totalSleep >= waitForCloseTimeout And Not waitForCloseTimeout = 0 Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("Waiting too long for process to close")
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

End Module
```

and usage:

```
    Dim ieProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    ieProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe"
    ieProcess.Start()
    ieProcess.WaitForWindowHandleToClose(1000, 20000, 20000)
```

Comment: I'll have to change this to task.delay

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try this and see if it works for my situation.

Comment: Seems to work OK so far, thank you. How would I pass the URL argument though using this method? I tried adding a space like  `ieProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe "` and then adding the recurl variable with a & between, but that still doesn't seem to fire the passed URL. Tried varying combinations of things but I still can't get that passed URL through.

Comment: Ieprocess.startinfo.arguments is your application arguments for the process...as far as the syntax of what the argument value is...that's specific to ie...but I think if you put the URL there you are good

Comment: OK, I was able to actually figure out the arguments. I added: `ieProcess.StartInfo.arguments = recurl` and it worked. Interesting thing though is now I can click my application and IE is no longer kept in the foreground, so we're back at square 1. Without IE kept in the foreground in front of my application, the user can get lost easily and it negates the benefit of this method. Any ideas how to keep IE in the foreground (on top of my App) while the process is still running?

Comment: Ha! You beat me to it by 30 seconds. I did figure it out, thank you but see my comment above.

Comment: I do...but I'll have to get back to you on that tonight

Comment: so...this is how its done...youll need to separate the wait for the window handle to be created and the wait for the main window handle to be closed into 2 separate methods...in between...youll get a reference to that handle...and save it...then create an event in the form_activated...if the form is activated...youll use the win api call to setforegroundwindow and pass the process's window handle...that way whenever your form activates...the process will appear on top of it

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm in a little over my head now. I'm not that great of a programmer, but I'll try to implement what you mentioned.